# How to do a long exposure with a Nikon D60

Tags: nikon, exposure, long-exposure

I've searched google high and low for this and all I get are results trying to sell me camera equipment.

I have a Nikon D60 without the ML-L3 remote control, well I have one but the battery has run out. It's a marvellous star-lit night tonight but I'm damned if I can work out how to open an exposure on my Nikon D60 then close it again after an amount of time that I determine.

I've read the manual again but can't make head or tail of it. I'm an ex-film 35mm Minolta X300 user, I am having problems transitioning to digital.

Can anyone help me with settings? If I get a decent result I promise to post links.

Edit:

As per mattdm's suggestion I have rotated the mode to **M** but I am not able to manually control the exposure or work out how to put the camera into "bulb" mode. This is the copy of the manual I'm working from [here](http://www.nikonusa.com/pdf/manuals/dslr/D60_en.pdf).

The manual referenced above states:

> Shutter remains open while the shutter-release button is held down,
>   and closes when the  shutter-release button is released. This option
>   is available when shooting in d mode at a shutter speed of “Bulb”
>   (“bulb”  is displayed in the viewfinder) (A44).

I guess my question is....how do I set the shutter speed to "bulb"?

Comment: Sorry folks, I'm a bit old-school and used to working with my old film 35mm kit, I'm a bit overwhelmed with all these new fancy digital features.

Comment: On page 44 it is explained how to change the shutter speed in manual mode: `Shutter speed displayed in the viewfinder will change
as the command dial is rotated`

Comment: [This](http://pad2.whstatic.com/images/thumb/c/cd/Nikon_main_command_dial_350.jpg/521px-Nikon_main_command_dial_350.jpg) is the command dial by the way.

Comment: @BartArondson - Ok...I finally worked that out, thanks. I hadn't realise it would take quite a few rotations to eventually get to "bulb".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To set the shutter speed to *Bulb*, select **M** mode with the mode dial and then rotate the *command dial* located in the upper right corner on the back of the camera. Each click of the dial will change the shutter speed 1/3 stop. At one end of the scale will be the camera's maximum shutter speed: 1/4000 second. At the other end of the scale will be *Bulb*, one click past 30 seconds.

It is fairly clear on page 44 of the [D60 User's Manual](http://www.nikonusa.com/pdf/manuals/noprint/D60_ennoprint.pdf).

[image]

Comment: Much appreciated and clear now, I need to spend more time away from mode **A**.

Answer (score 2):

This is on [page 44 of the manual](http://www.nikonusa.com/pdf/manuals/noprint/D60_ennoprint.pdf). You apparently need to have the remote control to do a timed exposure. But, you can do a *bulb* exposure, where the shutter is held open as long as you manually hold the shutter release, by putting the camera in `M` mode and changing the shutter to past `30s` to `bulb`.

Answer (score -1):

You can either go to S mode and set the shutter speed to 30'' for 30 seconds of exposure and press the button and leave it or go to M mode and keep hold of the button for a controlled amount of exposure

Comment: The question is mostly about how using the bulb mode (*how do I set the shutter speed to "bulb"?*) and the accepted answer already discussed this. You are not bringing new data...